# Swift 3: NSNotification vs Notification

Tags: swift3

In Swift 3, what are the differences between `Notification` vs `NSNotification`?

Specifically, in Notification struct, there is a ReferenceType typealias of `NSNotification`. How is ReferenceType being used here?

```
public struct Notification : ReferenceConvertible, Equatable, Hashable {

    public typealias ReferenceType = NSNotification
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Notification` is a struct wrapper around `NSNotification`. You can bridge between the two using `as`, which is what `ReferenceConvertible` does.

Comment: Since it's a wrapper, why can't I just use NSNotification directly? Can you explain how ReferenceConvertible work?

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to use it directly because it's a wrapper? and ReferenceConvertible is compiler magic, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Boon `ReferenceType` is a decoration for Swift value types which are backed by a Foundation reference type. As Alexander says, it's used by the compiler for casting between NSNotification and Notification. We don't need to worry about it, it's an internal mechanism.

Comment: So can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: @MobileMon Yes, though you should generally prefer the non `NS` variant in Swift.